# Access iCloud key-value storage on my device

Tags: macos, ios, icloud

I’m interested in seeing what type of information apps on my iPhone & Mac are storing in [key value storage](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html).

I tried downloading my iCloud data from privacy.apple.com but was not able to find any data that seemed to be stored in a key-value fashion.

Does anyone know where I can access this data? Either from my device or downloading it through an iCloud interface.